# The JSON my function POST's is different to what I pass to it

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, post

I have this function which is meant to POST JSON obtained from a GitHub API call:

```
    postToDb: function(body) {
        var http = require("http");
        var options = {
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port: 9000,
            path: '/issues',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: body
        };
        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (body) {
                console.log('Body: ' + body);
            });
        });
        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
        });
        // write data to request body
        req.write('{"string": "Hello, World"}');
        req.end();

    }
```

However something like `{"_id":"5b7c6d0457de7d6c7c4ae85b","__v":0}` gets POST'ed instead. This is what I expected:

```
{
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TestOrg/test2/issues/4",
    "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TestOrg/test2",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TestOrg/test2/issues/4/labels{/name}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TestOrg/test2/issues/4/comments",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TestOrg/test2/issues/4/events",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/TestOrg/test2/issues/4",
    "id": 347593311,
    "node_id": "MDU6SXNzdWUzNDc1OTMzMTE=",
    "number": 4,
    "title": "test issue 2",
    "user": {
      "login": "my-repo",
      "id": 32067576,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjMyMDY3NTc2",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/32067576?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/my-repo",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/my-repo/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "labels": [],
    "state": "open",
    "locked": false,
    "assignee": null,
    "assignees": [],
    "milestone": null,
    "comments": 0,
    "created_at": "2018-08-04T06:34:50Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-08-04T06:34:50Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "author_association": "CONTRIBUTOR",
    "body": "In order to help resolve your issue as quickly as possible please provice the following information when \r\n\r\n1. What is the issue?\r\nAnother one!\r\n\r\n2. What are the steps to recreate the issue?\r\n\r\n\r\n3. Do you have any relevant code samples? If so, please provice them.\r\n\r\n\r\n4. Have you made any specific configurations?\r\n\r\n\r\n5. Do you get an error? If so please include it and any stack trace.\r\n\r\n\r\n6. What version of the API are you using?\r\n",
    "performed_via_github_app": null,
    "score": 1
  }
```

It seems `getGitHubIssues.postToDb(issueFormatForDb);` passes the correct JSON but the body inside `var req` is different. I'm sure this is just something I don't yet understand. Could somebody please explain what is happening here and how I could change this function to POST the correct JSON?

Comment: It's not just a miskmask between body and mybody?  Seems like you pass a undefined content

Comment: Sorry, that was left over from some experimenting I did and forgot to change it back. mybody is now gone.

Comment: You need to setup a Postman to see what actual happening

Comment: Thanks @split. Checking Postman put me on the right track. The issue was that I had changed the JSON I'm POST'ing but forgot to update my Schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments above. I had updated the JSON I'm POST'ing but forgot to update my schema.